# php merging 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 x 2D arrays with values returned from the database.

Currently I am doing a foreach loop and putting the returned values onto a separate table per array:

eg:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Auto Bavaria Midrand BMW</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>39</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Auto Bavaria Midrand BMW</td>
  <td>40</td>
  <td>15</td>
  ...
</tr>
</table>
```

But I need to return the values in this format, in only 1 table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Auto Bavaria Midrand BMW</td>
    //the name of the record does not need to be repeated, only the values
    <td>63</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>40</td> //values from 2nd array
    <td>15</td> // values from 2nd array
  </tr>
        ...//next record set
</table>

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DealerName] => Auto Bavaria Midrand BMW
            [dealersContacted] => 63
            [DealerContact_Y] => 39
            [DealerContact_N] => 15
            [DealerShipId] => 21730
            [DataId] => 23527
        )
     //extra returned records 
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DealerName] => Auto Bavaria Midrand BMW
            [dealersContacted] => 65
            [DealerContact_Y] => 40
            [DealerContact_N] => 15
            [DealerShipId] => 21730
            [DataId] => 23527
        )

   //extra returned records 
)
```

I can do the php side of it, my question is if there is an array function that can merge only the needed bits of the array? I have searched and just gotten more and more confused.

Comment: I think the two examples he gives are supposed to be different. And yes, you'll need to loop thru the arrays yourself - there is no magic inbuilt function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change the way you build the array when fetching from the database, so that instead of a meaningless numerical index, you get a meaningful key. in your above example, you probably want to use `DealerName` as a key. That way, when you retrieve items, you just add them to the appropriate place. Example:

```
 while($rows = fetch_from_db($res)) {
    $output[$rows['DealerName']]['dealersContacted'] = $rows['dealersContacted'];
    $output[$rows['DealerName']]['DealerContact_Y']  = $rows['DealerContact_Y'];
    // Add more keys here
 }
```

that way when you finish retrieving both result sets, you have only one array left. You should also plan how to deal with double indexes, such as the dealersContacted in your example.